Does $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_n(x_i) \to \frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega f$ in some sense if $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ weakly in $L^2(\Omega)$?
I have a weakly converging sequence $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ on a bounded domain $\Omega$ and I know $f_n, f \in C^0(\bar\Omega)$. Define the Monte Carlo estimator function $$R_n(g) := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i)$$ where $x_1, ..., x_n$ are independent and uniformly distributed samples taken from $\Omega$. We know that
$$R_n(g) \to \frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega g.$$
Is there any kind of convergence $$R_n(f_n) \to \frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega f$$
that we can get? Pointwise would not be true. If the sequence $f_n$ converged strongly, then from my previous question we know that this above convergence would hold in $L^2(P)$. But here I have just weak convergence. Is there a notion of convergence that we can get? Or at the very last, can we say that $R_n(f_n)$ is bounded uniformly in $n$ in some space?

That situation might be too detailed to have existing work on it, but it seems like you should be able to obtain the result by yourself. Are you familiar with a proof of your statement that $R_n(g)$ converges to $E(g)$? If so, what difficulties are you running into when applying that proof to $R_n(f_n)$? If you don't know how to prove the law of large numbers, consider the mean and variance of $R_n(g)$ and apply chebyshev's inequality

@GuillaumeDehaene I'm not familiar with probability that much but maybe I should be. I will look into it, but do you have an idea of what kind of convergence mode might be possible?

I would guess that $R_n(f_n)$ converges the same as $R_n(g)$? Perhaps you need an additional condition? I'm honestly not sure it's that hard since you can control the behavior of $R_n(f_n)$ at any $n$. The steps are fairly straightforward. Compute mean and variance of $R_n(f_n)$. Apply Chebyshev to control the probability of deviations. Add convergence of $f_n \rightarrow f$ and conclude. The result most probably holds with weaker-than-L2 convergence, but it gets messier there.
